# Passing Pointers of Pointers to search xmlTree using libxml2

Tags: c, xml, pointers, libxml2

So I have and xml document I need to search for specific tags. I am using libxml2 and I have a function that will recursively search for nodes with the specified name and output the number of them. But then when I pass the same function an array to fill something weird is happening basically I think I should be passing a triple pointer but everything doesn't seem to be working right something is happening to the memory address I am passing the function. I am a beginner and I though I had a good handle on pointers but I think the typedef and multiple pointer layers is screwing me up. I did look though many post before posting this. Code compiles on my machine but I get a seg fault when I go to print the name of the collected nodes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libxml/xmlmemory.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>

int FindNodesByTagName(xmlNodePtr *ptr_array[], xmlNodePtr a_node, char tagname[]);

int main(void)
{

    int num_chan, k;
    xmlDocPtr doc;
    xmlNodePtr cur;
    xmlNodePtr *x;


char xstr[] = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
                "<chan>"
                "<blah>"
                    "<wrong>"
                        "<other>"
                            "<ele>some_text</ele>"
                            "<foo>"
                                "<enabled>true</enabled>"
                            "</foo>"
                            "<foo>"
                                "<enabled>true</enabled>"
                            "</foo>"
                        "</other>"
                    "</wrong>"
                "</blah>"
                "<blah>"
                    "<foo>"
                        "<enabled>true</enabled>"
                    "</foo>"
                    "<foo>"
                        "<enabled>false</enabled>"
                    "</foo>"
                "</blah>"
                "<enabled>false</enabled>"
                "<enabled>true</enabled>"
                "</chan>";

    doc = xmlParseMemory(xstr, sizeof(xstr) / sizeof(*xstr) );

    cur = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);

    num_chan = FindNodesByTagName(NULL, cur, "enabled");

    x = calloc(sizeof(xmlNodePtr), num_chan);

    FindNodesByTagName(&x, cur, "enabled");

    for(k=0; k < num_chan; k++)
        printf("%s\n", x[k]->name);

    printf("%i\n", num_chan);
    free(x);
    return 0;
}

int FindNodesByTagName(xmlNodePtr *ptr_array[], xmlNodePtr a_node, char tagname[]){

    int counter = 0;
    xmlNode *cur_node = NULL;
    int isElementNode;
    int isTagName;

    for (cur_node = a_node; cur_node; cur_node = cur_node->next){
        isElementNode = (cur_node->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE);
        isTagName = !xmlStrcmp(cur_node->name, (const xmlChar *) tagname);
        if (isElementNode & isTagName){
            counter ++;
            if (ptr_array != NULL) {
                **ptr_array = cur_node;
                /*printf("P2P %p, CA %p, DR %p, V %p\n", ptr_array, *ptr_array, **ptr_array, cur_node);*/
                (*ptr_array)++;
            }

        }
        counter += FindNodesByTagName(ptr_array, cur_node->children, tagname);
    }

    return counter;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Changes to make it run:

```
int FindNodesByTagName(xmlNodePtr *ptr_array[], xmlNodePtr a_node, char tagname[]);
// becomes
int FindNodesByTagName(xmlNodePtr ptr_array[], xmlNodePtr a_node, char tagname[]);

FindNodesByTagName(&x, cur, "enabled");
// becomes
FindNodesByTagName(x, cur, "enabled");

int FindNodesByTagName(xmlNodePtr *ptr_array[], xmlNodePtr a_node, char tagname[]){
// becomes
int FindNodesByTagName(xmlNodePtr ptr_array[], xmlNodePtr a_node, char tagname[]){

**ptr_array = cur_node;
// becomes
*ptr_array = cur_node;

(*ptr_array)++;
// becomes
ptr_array++;
```

I find `xmlNodePtr` being a disguise for `xmlNode *` abhorrent. The very first thing I did to fix this was convert all `xmlNodePtr` to `xmlNode *`.

Looking at the changes, I blame `xmlNodePtr` for most of the confusion. Anyway, remember that in something like `void foo(int bar[])` is the same as `void foo(int * bar)`. Hopefully you can see from the diff where you went wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply I realized after I read your comments that my example XML string wasn't sufficiently complicated as the approach you point out is what I started with originally but was having problems with because of the recursive call. This is why I was going down the road of pointer to pointer array. I edit my code with a more complex XML string. I did try what you suggested with the new XML string and get a seg fault after printing two names.

Answer (score 0):

So the code below works I still cannot quiet wrap my head around why I cannot pass just pass the function FindNodesByTagName &x. I know it has to do with pass by reference and pass by value and the fact I am manipulating that value in the function but I still can't get it all quiet worked out. For the moment I am moving forward with the minor inconvenience that I have to assign to another variable and then pass a pointer to that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libxml/xmlmemory.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>

int FindNodesByTagName(xmlNodePtr *ptr_array[], xmlNodePtr a_node, char tagname[]);

int main(void)
{

    int num_chan, k;
    xmlDocPtr doc;
    xmlNodePtr cur;
    xmlNode **x, **t;


    char xstr[] = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
                "<chan>"
                "<blah>"
                    "<wrong>"
                        "<other>"
                            "<ele>some_text</ele>"
                            "<foo>"
                                "<enabled>true</enabled>"
                            "</foo>"
                            "<foo>"
                                "<enabled>true</enabled>"
                            "</foo>"
                        "</other>"
                    "</wrong>"
                "</blah>"
                "<blah>"
                    "<foo>"
                        "<enabled>true</enabled>"
                    "</foo>"
                    "<foo>"
                        "<enabled>false</enabled>"
                    "</foo>"
                "</blah>"
                "<enabled>false</enabled>"
                "<enabled>true</enabled>"
                "</chan>";

    doc = xmlParseMemory(xstr, sizeof(xstr) / sizeof(*xstr) );

    cur = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);

    num_chan = FindNodesByTagName(NULL, cur, "enabled");

    x = calloc(sizeof(xmlNode *), num_chan);

    t = x;

    FindNodesByTagName(&t, cur, "enabled");

    for(k=0; k < num_chan; k++)
        printf("%s\n", x[k]->name);

    printf("%i\n", num_chan);
    free(x);
    return 0;
}

int FindNodesByTagName(xmlNode ***ptr_array, xmlNodePtr a_node, char tagname[]){

    int counter = 0;
    xmlNode *cur_node = NULL;
    int isElementNode;
    int isTagName;

    for (cur_node = a_node; cur_node; cur_node = cur_node->next){
        isElementNode = (cur_node->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE);
        isTagName = !xmlStrcmp(cur_node->name, (const xmlChar *) tagname);
        if (isElementNode & isTagName){
            counter ++;
            if (ptr_array != NULL) {
                **ptr_array = cur_node;
                printf("P2P %p, CA %p, DR %p, V %p\n", ptr_array, *ptr_array, **ptr_array, cur_node);
                (*ptr_array)++;
            }

        }
        counter += FindNodesByTagName(ptr_array, cur_node->children, tagname);
    }

    return counter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I have a different solution now after poking around a bit. I still don't like it. It still essentially has two steps and it seems to me there should be a way to do it all in one. In this version FindNodesByTagName is essentially a wrapper so that I can make a to the pointer to the current array address. For this wrapper I have also changed the signature of the function so the user can pass the pointer to the allocated array directly which I think is more intuitive.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libxml/xmlmemory.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>

int FindNodesByTagName(xmlNode *ptr_array[], xmlNode *a_node, char tagname[]);
int search_tag(xmlNode ***ptr_array, xmlNode *a_node, char tagname[]);

int main(void)
{

    int num_chan, k;
    xmlDocPtr doc;
    xmlNodePtr cur;
    xmlNode **x;

    char xstr[] = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
                "<chan>"
                "<blah>"
                    "<wrong>"
                        "<other>"
                            "<ele>some_text</ele>"
                            "<foo>"
                                "<enabled>true</enabled>"
                            "</foo>"
                            "<foo>"
                                "<enabled>true</enabled>"
                            "</foo>"
                        "</other>"
                    "</wrong>"
                "</blah>"
                "<blah>"
                    "<foo>"
                        "<enabled>true</enabled>"
                    "</foo>"
                    "<foo>"
                        "<enabled>false</enabled>"
                    "</foo>"
                "</blah>"
                "<enabled>false</enabled>"
                "<enabled>true</enabled>"
                "</chan>";

    /*
     * Parse string and get root element
     */
    doc = xmlParseMemory(xstr, sizeof(xstr) / sizeof(*xstr) );
    cur = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);

    /*
     * Find number of elements with particular tag name and allocate memory
     * then print out some debug info about them.
     */
    num_chan = FindNodesByTagName(NULL, cur, "enabled");
    x = calloc(sizeof(xmlNode *), num_chan);

    printf("\nAllocated memory before FindNodes\n");
    for(k=0; k < num_chan; k++)
        printf("%i-%p-%p\n", k, x+k, x[k]);

    /*
     * Call FindNodes again this time passing the allocated array to be
     * filled and then print some more debug info to confirm the array was
     * filled correctly.
     */
    FindNodesByTagName(x, cur, "enabled");

    printf("\nAfter FindNodes\n");
    for(k=0; k < num_chan; k++)
        printf("%i-%p-%s\n", k, x[k], x[k]->name);

    free(x);
    return 0;
}

int FindNodesByTagName(xmlNode *ptr_array[], xmlNode *a_node, char tagname[]) {
    /*
     * This function is now essentially just a wrapper and search_tag is
     * doing all the real work.
     */
    int counter;
    xmlNode ***ptr = NULL;

    if (ptr_array)
        ptr = &ptr_array;
    counter = search_tag(ptr, a_node, tagname);

    return counter;
}


int search_tag(xmlNode ***cur_idx, xmlNode *a_node, char tagname[]) {

    int counter = 0;
    int isElementNode;
    int isTagName;
    xmlNode *cur_node = NULL;

     for (cur_node = a_node; cur_node; cur_node = cur_node->next){
        isElementNode = (cur_node->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE);
        isTagName = !xmlStrcmp(cur_node->name, (const xmlChar *) tagname);
        if (isElementNode & isTagName){
            counter ++;
            if (cur_idx != NULL) {
                **cur_idx = cur_node;
                (*cur_idx)++;
            }
        }
        counter += search_tag(cur_idx, cur_node->children, tagname);
     }
     return counter;
}
```

The code compiles for me with the following command

```
gcc `xml2-config --cflags` name_of_file.c `xml2-config --libs`
```